# Place Footer at bottom of page with short text

Tags: footer, location-search

I have tried various solutions and end up using page specific css to place the footer at the bottom of a page with little text:
.site-footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

I am after a flexible solution that works on any page regardless of the amount of content. The difficulty I have is identifying the appropriate tags to apply the css to. I am using the customify theme and elementor page builder.

How do I identify "body" or "main" as proposed in this solution: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffb34dCmMVQ.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffb34dCmMVQ)

body {
display: flex
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 100vh;}

main{
flex-grow: 1;}

Comment: body and main seems to be html tags, you can use also classes and id's to have the same result, with elementor its probable the best solutin

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still having difficulty identifying which elements should be targetted with what css.
This is my test page: https://ihasa.org.au/aa/